# Node.js / JavaScript - JavaScript window variable breaking functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

So on my Jade template, I am passing it a variable through the route which contains an array of names.

Here is the JavaScript from that template:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
  window.teams = !{JSON.stringify(teams)};
```

`teams` contains the array I spoke about. Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  // Array of team names
  var teamNames = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    teamNames.push(teams[i].name);
  }

  var bracketTeams = [];

  var teamMatches = new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<teamNames.length; i+=2)
  {       
    teamMatches.push([teamNames[i],teamNames[i+1]]);
  }

  var bracketData = {
    teams : teamMatches,
    results : [[
        [ [1, 0], [1, 0] ],
        [ [1, 0], [1, 0] ]
      ]]
  }
    $('#tournamentBrackets').bracket({
        init: bracketData
    });
});
```

Now for some reason, the functionality of the rest of the system completely breaks when I add in this JavaScript code. If I comment it out, then the rest of the system works fine, if I leave it in, buttons do nothing, links go nowhere, data isn't added (although the data is loaded, i.e a database of teams is listed). If I load the page, then uncomment the JS, the page works as it should though.

Any ideas what is breaking my system in this code? I just tried renaming window.teams to window.testName and it still broke. Really confused.

EDIT: HTML generated

http://pastebin.com/VdkEfANb

Comment: i though jade require a - before each line of javascript code

Comment: @Four_lo Nope, the code is below the `script` tag which is okay in Jade, works for all my other code

Comment: @Four_lo It's something to do with the window.teams I'm sure, but I don't understand what....

Comment: @germainelol: You're getting an error somewhere. Check your JS console.

Comment: @Blender How to do that? I've only got my terminal open running Node.js

Comment: @germainelol: Is this code running serverside or clientside?

Comment: @Blender clientside I believe

Comment: @germainelol: Then open the JS console of your web browser. You're probably getting an error on this line: `teamMatches.push([teamNames[i],teamNames[i+1]]);`

Comment: @Blender The window variable `teams` is not defined is the error I get. No idea how to fix that though

Comment: @germainelol: Is the JS `<script>` block that defines `window.teams` above or below the code that you posted above?

Comment: @Blender The JS script defining `window.teams` is at the bottom of my Jade template, the block above is a separate file.

Comment: @germainelol: Right, but the order matters.

Comment: @Blender Should also add that the `teams` value in the JSON section of that script is sent only when this page loads as its only used for this page

Comment: @germainelol: Can you post the *entire* generated HTML file?

Comment: @Blender I will attach it as a pastebin link in the OP as it is too long due to some generated code, one second.

Comment: @Blender see OP now. Sorry for the bad formatting...

Comment: @germainelol: Move that last `<script>` tag up before the tag that uses the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js, the `window` object probably does not exist. Node.js has a different global object than browsers do. In Node.js, the global object is actually named `global`. Unless you have specifically set up an object named `window`, you're probably getting a ReferenceError when you try to assign values to `window.teams`

Comment: So you're saying it should be should be `global.teams` rather than `window.teams`?

Comment: Just saw your updated post, I have tried `global.teams` instead but the brackets generated from my JS don't actually appear when doing that, so it doesn't take in the value in my JS file using global

Comment: And sorry to post again, but if I load comment out the JS file I am using, load the page, uncomment the JS file, the page does actually load successfully and functions, but then when navigating to other pages doesn't work again. So the `window.teams` value is loading, but breaking the system

Comment: See BOM and DOM for other stuff you shouldn't expect to see in non-client-side web JS. Also I suspect global is only going to work in the context of any given file.

Comment: @ErikReppen Not sure what that means, ryanbrill is correct though, in the JS console, `window.teams` is not defined, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: He's right. Window doesn't exist in Node. There's no browser window in Node.js. Just like there's no document object. Do some googling. ECMA Script is all you can count on in Node. Browser stuff is covered by the W3C DOM, BOM and other APIs I'm no doubt forgetting. ECMA is Array, Date, String, Number, and other programmey essentials plus whatever Node.js defines as core library stuff. But no window.

Comment: @ErikReppen I see, I have passed the data to the Jade page through the app's GET route for that page, how would you recommend passing that data to the JS file then? This is the only way I could think of...

Comment: @gamerinelol Now that I see your pastebin, I see that you're not actually accessing the `window` object from Node.js. The problem looks to be that the JSON object is being escaped - `"` have been escaped to `&quot;` which is going to be causing a JS error in the browser.